# Crystal Report connection information file path?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

I am working on C# Crystal Reports, I added a new Crystal Report from the solution explorer and then I tried to add dot net objects from database fields. But when I am adding any class object this screen pops up, I don't know the file path of XML.

[image: This is the screen shot]

Comment: Filepath will be the data file which you need for data on crystal report. Simply try adding a dummy xml file on desktop and give that path. Later you can change the same.

Comment: I did not gave any xml data file i have model classes.

Comment: Since you are connecting to database, please follow this, and check if you are selecting incorrect source type ,http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/create-crystal-report-step-by-step-using-sql-database-view/

Comment: i just want to know the xml file path.

Comment: #lti Tyagi what data should be in dummy xml file?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20632/Reporting-XML-data-using-Crystal-Reports

Answer (score 0):

as U changes the Location of Project this Dialog Pops.You have to add the tables Database Fields all over again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).